# Custom Ajax File Uploader, Issue with .AjaxSubmit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a multipart form to upload images via AJAX.

The HTML is the following:

```
    <form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- This is a imagen like a button in the HTML -->
    <img class="anchor_tag" onclick="trigger_img('#');" height="92" width="122" id="addimage_#" src="/some/image/path" alt="#">

    <!-- File input hidden -->
    <input style="display:none;" type="file" name="photoimg_#" id="photoimg_#" class="upload">

</form>
```

When the user click the "Upload Button" with .anchor_tag class, I execute this js:

```
    function trigger_img(divID) {
     $("#photoimg_" + divID).trigger('click');
     $('#photoimg_' + divID).change(function() {
         var options = {
             url: 'http://www.someURL.com/Here/iHave/SomePHP',
             type: "GET",
             complete: function(data) {
                 // Do Something
             }
         };
         $('#mainform').ajaxSubmit(options);
     });
 }
```

If I try to upload a file, the console drop this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error is in this line:

```
$('#mainform').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

The PHP file is ok because the file is "Uploaded" broken.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have a jquery plugin included. ajaxSubmit is not a core function in jQuery.

Maybe you could try this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes as I said ajaxSubmit is not a core function.

Comment: Well, What plugin I have to include?

Comment: Look at my answer, I just posted the URL.

Comment: I included the function inside the document ready and, now, I have the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: trigger_img is not defined "